# How to use any() to apply to a particular nested list only?

Tags: python, arraylist

I'm trying to code the movement of points, but I don't want the points to overtake. Each point has an increasing velocity (up until a max value) unless there is another point ahead of it.

Array a is a series of distances between the points relative to each other which are nested/divided by each point. Array b is a set of velocities (initially starting from rest).

If the velocity + 1 + any value in the nested distance = 0, then I don't want the velocity to increase. However, when I apply the any function it seems to apply to the whole array, not the particular nested list I want:

```
import numpy as np
a = [[-1, -3], [1, -2], [3, 2]] #relative distances of each point
b = np.zeros(3) #velocities
for count, i in enumerate(a):
    if b[count] + 1 + any(a[count]) == 0:
        b[count] == b[count]
    else:
        b[count] += 1
print(b)
```

The output is [1. 1. 1.], but I would want [0.,1.,1.]. Am I applying it wrong? Let me know if you need any further clarifications

Comment: `any(data) == 0` doesn't mean "does any item in the data equal zero" it means "is the result of calling `any` on `data` equal to zero"

Comment: I think you want `any(x == 0 for x in i)`

Comment: any(a[count]) returns True when count is 0,
then True value is 1 when you do the addition+.
So 0 + 1 + 1 != 0 ....
Maybee this is you problem ?
Could you give details about what you expect here?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're applying it wrong.  You want to know whether any of the sums you cited is equal to zero -- so you have to apply `any` to the expression.  You applied it to the `a` row, which simply asks whether any element of this row is "truthy".

```
if any( (b[count] + 1 + a_component) == 0
        for a_component in a[count]):
```

Why do you have a non-functional assignment in a clause?  Negate your logic:

```
if not ... :
    b[count] += 1
```

... and no `else` clause